# AWS SNS call from Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am creating a Lambda (Java) where I need to do an AWS SNS topic call (Email) from my Java code, if my value exceed a particular Threshold limit. I have already created a topic to Publish and I have my topic ARN for subscription.
The code, so far:

```
if(list.get(0)<=25000) {
        System.out.println("Minimum" + list.get(0));
        //call SNS to send Alert//


    }else {
        System.out.println("Maximum" + list.get(list.size()-1));
    }
```

////My SNS Utility//

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient();
    String message = "My SMS message";
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = 
            new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
   String topicArn = "<my_topic_arn>";
     sendSMSMessageToTopic(snsClient, topicArn, message, smsAttributes);
}
public static void sendSMSMessageToTopic(AmazonSNSClient snsClient, String topicArn, 
        String message, Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes) {
        PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest()
                        .withTopicArn(topicArn)
                        .withMessage(message)
                        .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

Questions:

1. How do I call the SNS Utility in the my first `if` condition?

Comment: What is your question? Where do you stuck and what can we do to help you? Please clearify your question

Comment: 1. how do i call the SNS Ulitily in the my first given `if` condition? 2. I want to send email notification instead of sms, how do i do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to receive an email when a message is sent to an SNS topic? If so, the answer is that you need to create a Subscription on the SNS topic with a type of Email. If you do not wish to use an SNS topic, then you would need to use Amazon SES instead of Amazon SNS.

Comment: @John I have already created a topic and already made a subscription. I am hardcoding the `String topicArn` to whatever ARN i got while creating topic. I am not knowing how to call this method in my `if` condition(1st code snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would call the [`publish()` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#publish-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). There are several versions, such as:

```
public PublishResult publish(String topicArn,
                             String message,
                             String subject)
```

Comment: Thanks John, my result is showing in console, with the Message ID. But i still have not received the email notification that it was suppose to send.

Comment: Did you [confirm the email subscription request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html)? What is being displayed in the console for the subscription list to that topic, against that email address?

Comment: Yes. Also i tried it manually from the AWS SNS console..it worked then. In my console i am getting the result printed using `Sysyem.out.Println(result);` I got this in my console: `{MessageId: 6a126312-aae2-5380-a063-32ec97c46c14}`

Comment: What are you seeing in the console when you go into the SNS topic and look at the subscriber list? If the email subscription is confirmed, you should see an ARN in **Subscription ID** column, and a Protocol of **email**. Did you click the link in the email asking you to confirm the subscription?

Comment: Yeah, i did click the link while asking for confirmation. Also earlier today, some 4 hrs ago, i was testing it from my SNS console, clicking my topic and publishing a message. It worked successfully and I received the email notification. Is it like it works for just one time?

Comment: Once it is confirmed, any message sent to the topic will be sent to all the subscribers, regardless of protocol.

Comment: Thanks john, i am receiving alert as suppose to. I guess it was some network issue at that point of time.